# Java : The constructor JSONTokener(InputStreamReader) is undefined

Tags: java, json, compatibility, inputstream, tokenize

I have a quite strange issue with Java, I'm getting an error on some machines only, I would like to know if there is any way I can avoid that:

This is the line of code concerned:

```
JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(
                new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
```

This is the error I get on some machines

```
The file *.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The constructor JSONTokener(InputStreamReader) is undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the classpath on the machines where this error occurs. This could happen because the library that contains the `JSONTokener` class is from an older version, where only the `JSONTokener(String)` is available, and not `JSONTokener(Reader)`.