# How to check which library contains a specific class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting this error:

> Java : The constructor JSONTokener(InputStreamReader) is undefined

I found the latest version of [json](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm) and add that library but the problem didn't resolved, which I guess is because it is using another library.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725541/java-the-constructor-jsontokenerinputstreamreader-is-undefined) I need to find which library contains JSONTokener.How can I do that? None of the libraries' names contains json! I am using eclipse.

This is the import line of my program for this class:

```
import org.json.*;
```

Comment: You say you added a library; did you alter the build path of the project to include the library, or did you just copy the jar file into the project?  You need to do the former as well as the latter.

Comment: Click on the "Link with Editor" icon at the top of the project explorer. Then hit Ctrl-shift-T (Cmd-shift-T on Mac) and enter JsonTokener. Select the JsonTokener class in the list, look which jar the selected class is part of in the project explorer.

Comment: If you use eclispe and you want to check which class is in which jar, you can do ctrl + shift + t , which is 'open type', type the class name, it will list out available jars in which class you typed is present

Comment: @arcy yes I added that.

Comment: Thank you guys, ctrl+shift+t did the trick. It is using "google-api-translate-java0.92.jar". I removed that, and added the latest verison of json, and everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

To the OP: note also that as well as configuring the list of libraries, jars, folders, etc. in the build path, you may have to manually-adjust their order (using the 'Order and Export' tab).